# elegant way to switch from python to python3 automatically

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python code that I want it to stick with python3. But sometimes I forget it is a python3 code and run it like that:

```
$ python foo.py
```

I adopt a strategy like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys,os,warnings

if sys.version_info < (3,0):
    sys.argv.insert(0,__file__)
    warnings.warn("Switch back to python3 automatically")
    os.execv("/usr/bin/python3",sys.argv)
```

Is there any elegant way to do the same thing?

Comment: Since you put `#!/usr/bin/python3` just launch it with `./foo.py`.

Comment: And if you require Python3: Don't magically re-execute the script, which can cause all sorts of breakage. Just make the script croak and die.

Comment: @polku I know. But the code is a module of the main program, there is some test case under if __name__ == "__main__". I will not "chmod +x" it. I test it by "python3 foo.py".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to make it executable, then you can create a small script run_foo.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
python3 foo.py
```

then

```
./run_foo.sh
```

I think it's still better than an execv in your code for personal convenience.